# Requests timeout erro

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I write this code and it has "timeout error".
I have tried many solutions but the problem isnt solved.
This is my code:

```
import requests
from pytube import YouTube

save_path = "C:/Desktop"

link = "https://youtu.be/A54_QPXdkU0"

responce = requests.get(link, timeout=10)
video = YouTube(responce)
stream = video.streams.get_audio_only()
stream.download(output_path = save_path)
```

error:

requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='youtu.be', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /A54_QPXdkU0 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000019246A7F460>, 'Connection to youtu.be timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))

I write any number and "None" for timeout but the problem wasnt solved.

Pleas help me for solve this problem.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

This thing usually happens when you send too many requests to the public IP address. You have to wait for some time and then try again.

Comment: I tried this (after two days) but it doesnt work.

Comment: @The_Alireza make sure youre not using this on some server like google console or replit etc . Pytube doesnt work there , you can try using yt-dl or ytdlp . they are far more better